# Delphi TRibbon ToolTip for buttons

Tags: delphi, ribbon, vcl

I am trying to add a ToolTip (or hint as Delphi refers to it) to the buttons on the ribbon.   I am using the TRibbon that comes with Delphi XE7.  I am developing in the VCL framework.

I did find a Hint property in the Action that is linked to the button on the Ribbon, but I cannot get the Hint to display.

So it seems that the correct answer is to set ShowHint = True on the form.

Comment: Does the form (and possibly the ribbon) have `ShowHint = True`?

Comment: Do you have a TScreenTipsManager on the form? It's typically how you set up tips for the ribbon and its controls, IIRC. There's an example of its use in the Ribbon samples that used to be deployed with the IDE if you have an earlier version available to you. (Why they removed them in more recent versions is beyond me, since the components still exist and work the same way, and the demos still work just fine in XE7.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd check if the form (and possibly the ribbon) have ShowHint = True.